# Como hacer que el contenido aparezca detrás de la barra de estado y detrás de la barra de navegación?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Como podría lograr que el contenido de la actividad aparezca detrás de la barra de estado y navegación a partir de versión 19 como en el del ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, @freddy esto no es una pregunta por lo que te diria que borres el post, ya que solo estas informando sobre lo que se puede realizar en Android.

Comment: Ya te puse una respuesta :D

Comment: Disculpa como puedo hacer que el contenido aparezca detrás de la barra de navegación , con esto mi pregunta estará respondida por completo nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: mmm, no se esta mostrando toda la pantalla ? como en la imagen o que falta?, podrias subir una imagen de como se ve ahorita ?

Comment: Tambien, que version es tu android?

Comment: Estoy diseñando con una versión de android 19 puedes ayudarme gracias

Comment: Podrias poner una imagen de como esta actualmente

Comment: Vale ya la puse

Comment: Hola lo veo igual :(

Comment: Esta vez es diferente

Comment: Quieras que se vea el fondo de inicio en tu app?

Comment: Quiero que mi fondo de pantalla de inicio se vea detrás de barra de estado y barra de navegación , te puse un ejemplo claro gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que cambiar algunas propiedades de tu estilo del `theme`

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

En el manifest a tu activity deberas agregar lo siguiente:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Por ultimo en tu activity agrega el siguiente codigo:

```
// In Activity's onCreate() for instance
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```